# Overloading equality operator

Tags: python, oop, operator-overloading

I am having a little issue with the proper overloading of comparison operators. I am trying to check full identity of 2 objects of the same class.
My logic is to have, sth like that:

```py
    def __init__(self, name, num):
        self._name = name
        self._scores = []
        for _ in range(num):
            self._scores.append(0)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.name == other.name and self.num== other.num:
            for j in range(1, self.num):  # range from index 1
                if self.getScore(j) != other.getScore(j):
                    return False
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

What I receive is...:

```
AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute 'name'
```

I am trying to change b/w private/protected/public but still I am unable to operate with the operator overloaded method.

Comment: U have `_name` only

Answer (score 1):

Your code is using `self._name` and your comparison is using `self.name` which is why it can't find `self.name` because it should be `_name`

Comment: @ii-k if this answers your question please mark it as answered.